# Main view rotates from center point to 360 degree but inner views are also being rotated

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

[image: Rotation of MainView and Inner views are added Check saturn image added, Saturn image rotated]
[image: Original Saturn image, I want to add image as it is onto main view]

I am rotating main view with 360 degrees, and I have subviews added inside main view, everything works correctly, but with one issue.

What I want to do is when I rotate main view, inner views should not lost their frames/position. Right now, when I rotate main view with infinte repeat count and dynamically if I add subview inside main view, it goes into proper position, but it does not retain its frame.

For example, I am implementing orbit, and for that, I have used entire transparent view as orbit and orbit is rotated from center point to 360 degree infinite times, and User can add many planets as he wants onto orbit, so when planets added on orbit, planets do not retain its frame. Can you suggest any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'planets do not retain its frame'? I don't understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: when you rotate main view, inner views are also rotated, but it will give impression, like let say: if you add "cup" image as sub view onto mainview and that main view is rotated, so when cup is added, when cup goes to top, cup image will be down, and when cup goes to bottom, cup image will be upside, so I want that cup image should be as it is. it should also be upside when cup goes to top during rotation animation.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds like you need to add a rotating animation for every subview that you add in your main view. If the main view rotates clockwise your subviews will need to rotate around their center in a counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: I have added images for better understanding of my question. :)

Comment: Yes, I am doing counter clockwise animation of subviews added, but main problem is when subview is added, it does not being added as image is actually

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to keep the subviews' orientations while rotating.
If I were you, I'd use CAAnimation instead of using a view to rotate.
You may add the animation to every subview, try this:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation* animation;
animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];    
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL,imgview.layer.position.x,imgview.layer.position.y);

int p =  [self getblank:tag];
float f = 2.0*M_PI  - 2.0*M_PI *p/PHOTONUM;
float h = f + 2.0*M_PI *num/PHOTONUM;
float centery = self.view.center.y;
float centerx = self.view.center.x;
float tmpy =  centery + RADIUS*cos(h);
float tmpx =    centerx - RADIUS*sin(h);
imgview.center = CGPointMake(tmpx,tmpy);

CGPathAddArc(path,nil,self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y,RADIUS,f+ M_PI/2,f+ M_PI/2 + 2.0*M_PI *num/PHOTONUM,0);    
animation.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
animation.duration = TIME;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.calculationMode = @"paced";   
return animation;
```

Comment: What is PHOTONUM and what does this [self getblank:tag]; do?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! PHOTONUM is the number of subviews, and please ignore int p ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a stored variable that represents the rotation of the "world", correct?  If not, you should.

Then, for each image you add, also store a variable with it that represents its rotation to the world.

For example, if your world is rotated 180°, and you added a cup (which you want to appear right-side up when the world is upside-down) the cup's "offset" to the world rotation would be -180°.

Then, if the world is at 180° and you rotate your world by adding 90°, then the cup's new rotation value would be cup_rotate_offset + world_rotation,  or 180°+270°, which is the same as saying 90°, and the top of the world would be facing left and the cup's top would be facing right.

You have to independently track the offset values for each added object.